# How to use filter in a function (right positioning)

Tags: javascript

The aim of `oddCount(n)` is to output an array with odd positive numbers below `n`. Why `.filter` is not working inside `oddCount(n)`? `.filter` works only outside `oddCount(n)` in `console.log(arr.filter(num => num%2))`. There is something wrong, but I cannot spot it.

```css
const arr = []
function oddCount(n){
for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
arr.push(i)
}
arr.filter(num => num%2)

}
oddCount(7)
console.log(arr)
// expected => arr = [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't just doing `for(let i=1; i<n; i+=2)`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thank you for that, but the result is `arr = [0, 2, 4, 6]`. The expected result is instead `arr = [1, 3, 5]`. Any other thought?

Comment: Try reading my suggestion properly and actually use it. `let i=1`, not `i=0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter is working just fine, the code just isn't doing anything with the [new array it returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).  If you want to over-write `arr` with that new array, assign it:

```
arr = arr.filter(num => num%2);
```

Comment: thanks. I guess I need to transform `const arr` into `let arr`?

Comment: @Matteo: Ah yes, good catch.  A `const` will let you modify what a reference contains, but won't let you re-assign the reference so you would need to do that as well.